# Validating SSL certificate behind firewall

Tags: .net, ssl, firewall

I'm connecting to 3rd party services using SSL certificates. My server is running behind firewall with blocked outgoing traffic. The application is not able to validate the 3rd party certificate.

```
MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

The server's SSL certificate could not be validated for the following reasons:
• The server certificate has the following errors:
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
• An intermediate certificate has the following errors:
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
  • The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
```

I was trying to google how the client is validating certificate chain, but haven't found any. I'm especially interested at which ports and to which addresses the application / server is doing its validation queries.

As an immediate hotfix I had to allow plain HTTP outgoing traffic to all destinations.

Comment: OCSP server URL is written in root certificate. Must search for it there.

Comment: And OCSP is typically using plain HTTP, hence port 80. The URL to use may be in intermediate certificates too, not just the root (self signed) one.

Comment: Sounds like you need to [turn off revocation checking](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MailKit_IMailService_CheckCertificateRevocation.htm). (Really, it'd be better to set it for soft failure, but I don't see a way to do that.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson I am able to manage firewall rules, don't want to sacrifice security just because I don't know how things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OCSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) (Online Certificate Status Protocol) URL can be found in any level of the certificate chain (root, intermediate, leaf).

Based on [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167533/how-can-i-figure-out-which-ocsp-url-should-be-used-for-a-certificate-with-openss?newreg=292bcb9c5ee343b9908417e0038ef2ec) the applied url can be found using `openssl`:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -ocsp_uri
```

Fortunately *Fortigate* firewalls have main OCSP servers in their *Internet Service* database, so I don't need to check one by one.

Anyway there are few issues with OCSP implementation, [OCSP Stapling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCSP_stapling) is trying to address one of them.